# bash + how to avoiding duplicate entries in authorized_keys (ssh) in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, rhel, ssh-keygen

Popular methods of adding an ssh public key to a remote host’s `authorized_keys` file include using the `ssh-copy-id` command, and using bash operators such as `>>` to append to the file.

An issue with `ssh-copy-id` is that this command does not check if a key already exists. This creates a hassle for scripts and automation because subsequent runs can add duplicate key entries.

so I am using the following script  ( on rhel server version 7.8 )

```
more /tmp/test.sh

#!/bin/bash

PUB_KEY=` cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub `
grep -q -F \"$PUB_KEY\" ~/.ssh/authorized_keys 2>/dev/null || echo \"$PUB_KEY\" >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I an not sure if this is the best approach , so I will appreciate to get other ideas out of the box*

Comment: Hint: count the double quotes on that line. You don't want any of the quotes to be escaped, so remove the backslashes.

Comment: Because `$PUB_KEY` contains the filename not the contents. Try `PUB_KEY=$(cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)`

Comment: You have to remove the backlashes. In your `grep` and `echo`. `grep -q -F "$PUB_KEY" ... | echo "$PUB_KEY" ...`